# Detecting Count of Pulses in a Chart Series

Tags: c#, math, statistics

I have a line series on my chart. This is similar to a square wave as seen in the picture below. How can I count number of pulses in C#?

[image: Sample Line Series]

For those who wants to see some code can look at below. The idea is set a min and max value. For example if the point is between min and max and next time is not then I decide that there is an edge. However I have doubts about this idea especially with some noisy signals.

```
var K = new Queue<Point>(); // Point is a class that holds DateTime and double value as well as some other properties.

                foreach (var Point in Source.Data.OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp))
                {
                    K.Enqueue(new Point() { Timestamp = Point.Timestamp, Value = Point.Value, InBand = (Point.Value >= Min) && (Point.Value <= Max) });
                }


var Points = new Point[3];

                foreach (var Point in K)
                {
                    if (null == Points[0])
                    {
                        Points[0] = Point;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (null == Points[1])
                    {
                        Points[1] = Point;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (null == Points[2])
                    {
                        Points[2] = Point;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if ((Points[0].InBand == false) && (Points[1].InBand == true) && (Points[2].InBand == true))
                    {
                        this.RunCount++;

                        Points[0] = null;
                        Points[1] = null;
                        Points[2] = null;

                        continue;
                    }

                    if ((Points[0].InBand == true) && (Points[1].InBand == false) && (Points[2].InBand == false))
                    {
                        this.StopCount++;

                        Points[0] = null;
                        Points[1] = null;
                        Points[2] = null;

                        continue;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: How is this even implemented? We are going to need to see some code.

Comment: @gleng I have included some code. I'd rather you to purpose an algorithmn like Steve does than needing to comment on some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make the assumption that your data is stored in a `double[]`. In this case, you can iterate over the values, and count how many times the value goes from below some threshold to above that same threshold.

Here is a little sample of code that you should be able to adapt. I haven't tested it, but it's pretty straightforward. Note that if you have a very noisy signal, this will probably give you strange results, so filtering may be required. Also, the name of the method is a bit wrong since this counts the number of times the signal goes from *below* the threshold to *above* the threshold.

```
public int CountCrossings(double[] waveform, double threshold) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < waveform.Length - 1; i++) {
        if (waveform[i + 1] >= threshold && waveform[i] < threshold)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Steve. This gave me some idea to improve my solution.  However noisy signals are still problem. I'll ignore noise problem at this moment and consider signal is clear.